# jQuery Error: Expected ';' GetProductDetails?callback=jQuery19105298977986573554_1393335023879&_=1393335023880,

Tags: jquery, json, html, wcf, kendo-ui

I am getting this strange error while trying to make call to JSON Webservice using:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://localhost/KendoServices/Web/GetProductDetails",
                        dataType: 'jsonp'
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                schema: {
                    data: function (response) {
                        return response.d
                    }
                }
            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "OrderId",
                title: "OrderId",
                width: 140
            }, {
                field: "ProductId",
                title: "ProductId",
                width: 190
            }, {
                field: "UnitPrice",
                title: "UnitPrice"
            }, {
                field: "quanity",
                width: 110
            }]
        });
    });
  </script>
```

When I start browser console :

[image]

I am confused what is casuing the error. Service is returning JSON nice and fine.

Browser is able to call the service too. Then what's the error?

Service Implementation is as simple as :

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 List<ProductDetails> GetProductDetails();
```

So What's wrong?

Comment: @Shehary Please avoid making useless edits on old, off-topic questions.

Comment: @Shehary You seem to be on a spree of useless edits. I would suggest being extremely careful as uselessly editing old off-topic is not something the community appreciates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
return response.d
```

by this:

```
return response.d;
```

Comment: OMG! It was semicolon.

Comment: Wao , This was so tricky. Thanks